# Shell script: How to read filename between the arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I have problem with processing argument if there is file.
Its for my project, where I dont know how many arguments there will be, so I dont know the place of the file. My idea was to scan argument by argument and everytime do what that argument should do and that last argument (in most of time) is that file with data, which I will be reading as input.
For example, it has to work with:

```
$ ./corona daily osoby2.csv

$ ./corona -s 20 yearly osoby.csv

$ ./corona -g M osoby.csv | head -n 6

$ cat osoby.csv | ./corona yearly
```

etc...

I dont know the name of file and there could be more files (in function ,,merge,,)

Thanks for your advices.

```
#!/bin/bash

 a_num=1

 for argument in $*

 do 
    if [ -f $a_num ]
    then
      echo "yes"
      echo " argument = " $argument
    else
      echo " argument = " $argument 
    fi
    
 done
```

I tried simple loop for arguments to know if this could work, but when there is file at the end, it doesnt work and write: bash: ./corona: No such file or directory

Comment: Use `getopts` to parse the options. When you get to the end of the options, everything else is filenames, which you simply loop over.

Comment: But in some situations there isnt file at the end ($ cat osoby.csv | ./corona yearly). Doesnt exist something to automatically recognize the file? For example everything will be just argument and after read it will be sent to another function to find out if its command or file.

Comment: After the `getopts` loop, check if there are any more arguments. If not, process standard input instead of named files.